# Can I copy a video strip from one opened Blender into another?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I have a project where I have a video, I added to that video some text and I sped it up. I want to re-use that project/video within several other projects.

At the moment I have 2 blenders opened. One with that project, and another one, an empty one where I want to copy it. I tried using the append feature, and appending the scene, but that only appends a cube, not the video.

I could render into a movie, and then reuse the movie, but wouldnt that lower the quality?

Comment: if you appended your scene you should have both scenes now, and be able to switch between them -using the dropdown in info bar- also copy / paste video strips between them and delete one scene after that... have you saved your file?

Answer (score 4):

This works for me - pack the video into .blend using File -> External data -> Pack All into Blend.
Then from the other project select File -> Append, find the .blend with the packed videos and append the Scene datablock.
The video strips should be appended now.

Answer (score 4):

I have found that you can use copy <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and paste <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to copy a strip from one Blender project to another.  However, I have not been able to do this from one open copy to a different open copy of Blender.  What you need to do is

1. open the project you want to copy from
2. select the strip that you want to copy and type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
3. go to the file menu and either open a new project or open an existing project
4. place your cursor in the pane where the strips are shown
5. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

This works for me. I use Blender v2.76 on a Windows 10 computer.

Comment: Works also on Blender 3.3.1

Answer (score 4):

OK - I've found this to work...

1. In the file you want to copy strips **from**: Name the scene (I'd name it the same as the file) and save.
2. In the file you want to copy strips **to**: Append the scene from the other file.
3. You can now copy and paste strips with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

Lossless Video output is available if you want to draw on "Master Videos".  In the 'Encoding' tab under the video settings (at right) is a box called "Lossless Output".  Tick that.

This box comes up under the encoding format - H264.  Don't forget to click on it's RGB box at right.

Thanks also to @Jan Kadeřábek.  I've made a note of your answer. :)